# sun/io/MalformedInputException when trying to remotely connect to JMS queue on websphere

Tags: jms, websphere

I am aware that a (very) [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272877/how-to-solve-sun-io-malformedinputexception-during-jndi-lookup-on-remote-websphe) has been asked elsewhere but there are no answers so am posting here in the hope the new post will trigger some valuable responses.

I am trying to create a standalone app that will interrogate a JMS queue that is running on websphere.  The queues are running as local apps are able to communicate with it and there are messages sitting there waiting for me.

I am using Netbeans and am using JDK1.8.
In addition I have added the following jar files to the library:

```
javax.jms-1.1.jar
com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar
com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar
```

The latter two were copied from the websphere installation.

Here is a summary of the initial code (it is actually built in a class with methods for the context and factory bits so have modified it to show here):

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, corbaloc:iiop:192.168.254.202:2809);
try{
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);
}catch(NamingException e){
System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create JNDI context: " + System.lineSeparator() + e.toString());
System.exit(1);
}
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory= (ConnectionFactory) this.jndiContext.lookup(factory);
String outFactory       = "jndi/OUTConnectionFactory";
try{    
connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup(outFactory);
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create factory connection:");
System.out.println(e.toString());
System.exit(2); 
}
```

At this point (connectionFactory = ...) it fails without triggering the catch

```
Exception in thread "P=598328:O=0:CT" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/MalformedInputException
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.getTcsCConverter(CDRReader.java:398)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.readStringOrIndirection(CDRReader.java:479)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRReader.read_string(CDRReader.java:465)
    at com.ibm.rmi.IOR.read(IOR.java:335)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection._locate(Connection.java:480)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.locate(Connection.java:439)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:219)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.Corbaloc.locateUsingINS(Corbaloc.java:307)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.Corbaloc.resolve(Corbaloc.java:378)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.objectURLToObject(ORB.java:3721)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.objectURLToObject(ORB.java:3256)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.string_to_object(ORB.java:3619)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.stringToObject(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1645)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getWsnNameService(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1502)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1040)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at jmstool2.JmsConn.CreateFactCon(JmsConn.java:103)
    at jmstool2.JmsConn.connect(JmsConn.java:59)
    at jmstool2.Jmstool2.main(Jmstool2.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.MalformedInputException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
Java Result: 1
```

I am really not sure where to look to resolve this error. Is it a case of finding the right .jar file or library or are there bigger issues at play here?  I am a LAMP developer really and this dive into the world of Java and JMS queues is proving rather frustrating.

Many thanks

Comment: Additional related question
is the problem that:  sun/io/MalformedInputException  is missing or is that just the class that is reporting the error?

Comment: `I am using Netbeans and am using JDK1.8`. As was pointed in that other thread - Java 1.8 is not supported as client to  WebSphere 8.5. Please use Java 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: Will try that then Gas...sorry you had not posted there when I first looked.

Comment: I have moved to JDK 1.7 and that error has gone.  OK, I have another error 

(javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible )

 but at least I feel I can move foreward with this.

Comment: Ok, good that it helped a bit. Sorry I didn't notice your post was earlier :). I'll add it as an answer. Your other problem might be the SSL. Check this [post](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614221). You can create new question, if you will still have issues.

Comment: Hi again Gas.  I have recreated my little application on the server itself and indeed it is connecting there so looks like some security or permissions issue.  Websphere already had the iiop security settings set to SSL supported.  I just want to get on and programme...get deflated with these sorts of things as I just don't have experience with this side.  Thanks for you input.

Comment: Please find one more possible solution on [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36798643/3749321)

Comment: Thanks for keeping this post updated @ParanoidUser - 15 months after the original

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class `sun.io.MalformedInputException` doesn't exist in Java 8, and also Java 8 is not supported as client to WebSphere Application Server v 8.5. Please use Java 6 or 7.

Comment: I am in a similar situation - but I really want to use Java 8. its been just over an year since the last comment from @Gas.  I am wondering if things have changed and if I can now use Java 8.  if it benefits, I am using IBM JDK 8 inside WebSphere Liberty Profile

Comment: looks like there is a patch APAR from IBM: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IX90160